# __str__ returned non-string (type Category). when I add post from admin

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-admin

After I added user and date_added in the Photo models, when I add post from admin its throws me an error saying:   **str** returned non-string (type Category), when I click on the addpost link in the home template its throw another error: 'tuple' object has no attribute '**name**'. how can I solve that ?

the models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
    blank=True)
    image = CloudinaryField('image')
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

the view.py file:

```
def home(request):
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    if category == None:
        photos = Photo.objects.all()
    else:
        photos = Photo.objects.filter(category__name=category)
  
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories, 'photos': photos}
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'categories': categories, 'photos': photos} )


def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'phpto': photo})



class PostCreativeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Photo, Category
    fields = ['description', 'image', 'category', 'name']
    template_name = 'post_create.html'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (PostCreativeView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it has to do with your category name and model you added into post create view.py and so you
have do something like this:

```
views.py

class PostCreativeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Photo
    fields = ['description', 'image', 'category']
    template_name = 'post_create.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super (PostCreativeView, self).form_valid(form)

#.......

# Models.py 
class Photo(models.Model):
  #>>>...
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.category)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! Mark and vote as accepted answer , if my solution helped solve your problem others will benefit from it when they run into similar challenge. Its good to always accept and vote if a solution helped solved your problem that encourages others to help you solve your problems in the future. Thank you

Comment: Okay sir, I got it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should return the `str(…)` of the category, so:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.category)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. What about the link I click on my home templates, is a link that will direct me to the addpost template but when I click on it, it's throws an error AttributeError at post/create 'tupple' has no attribute '__name__' ?